# Turn greyscale into colorscale

Tags: matlab, colors, filtering

I am working on a Matlab script which applies a Laplacian filter to an image, and plots the result in greyscale. Do you have any suggestion on how to plot it using a colorscale instead?

Here is the code:

```
A=open('file.fits');
B=A.mcp;
H = fspecial('laplacian', 1); %fspecial creates a filter
I = imfilter(B, H);
figure;
imshow(I,[])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `imagesc`, or `imshow(im2uint8(I), jet(256))`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! With `imagesc` I got a blank graph, and `imshow(im2uint8(I), jet(256))` is all yellow... but `imagesc(im2uint8(I))` is a good starting point, showing all the features in red and blue. In case you have other ideas, what I want to do is to convert the various values of the laplacian in different colors ;-)

Comment: The resulting color depends on the range of `I`. Perhaps you may want to rescale `I` to fit in [0,1] range.

Comment: The dynamic range of the image in question may be very high.  Perhaps doing some sort of log transformation before doing `imagesc` may be fruitful.  BTW, @kyamagu, your `mexopencv` project is a lifesaver.  I used it to prototype something for work!